# AWS AppSync Offline mutations are getting updated to the server multiple times when the device is connected to the network

Tags: kotlin, graphql, apollo-client, aws-appsync, appsync-apollo-client

I'm using AWS AppSync Android SDK in my Project and i have noticed an issue that when i run a mutation it was working fine if the device is connected to the network, but if i do an offline mutation and then enabled my network, the same mutation is getting updated to the server multiple times. So i got a lot duplicate entries in my DB.

Tried different scenarios but the offline updations are getting called twice or thrice once the network connection is established.

//AppSyncClient Configuration class

class ClientFactory {

```
companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var mAWSAppSyncClient: AWSAppSyncClient? = null        
    private var cacheKeyResolver: CacheKeyResolver? = null
    private var appSyncSqlHelper: AppSyncSqlHelper?=null
    private var mNormalizedCacheFactory: SqlNormalizedCacheFactory?=null
    var  client:OkHttpClient?=null

    private lateinit var interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor
    @Synchronized
    fun getInstance(context: Context,utoken:String, dbName:String): AWSAppSyncClient? {
        if (cacheKeyResolver == null){
            cacheKeyResolver = object : CacheKeyResolver() {
                override fun fromFieldRecordSet(field: ResponseField, recordSet: Map<String, Any>): CacheKey {
                    val typeName = recordSet["__typename"] as String
                    if ("MessagesResponse" == typeName) {
                        val userKey = typeName + "." + recordSet["login"]
                        return CacheKey.from(userKey)
                    }
                    if (recordSet.containsKey("id")) {
                        val typeNameAndIDKey = recordSet["__typename"].toString() + "." + recordSet["id"]
                        return CacheKey.from(typeNameAndIDKey)
                    }
                    return CacheKey.NO_KEY
                }

                override fun fromFieldArguments(field: ResponseField, variables: Operation.Variables): CacheKey {
                    return CacheKey.NO_KEY
                }
            }
    }

        interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        appSyncSqlHelper = AppSyncSqlHelper.create(context, dbName)
        mNormalizedCacheFactory =  SqlNormalizedCacheFactory(appSyncSqlHelper)

        if(client==null) {
            val cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10MB
            client =
                OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(Cache(context.cacheDir, cacheSize.toLong())).addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .addNetworkInterceptor { chain ->
                        val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ".plus(utoken))
                            .build()
                        chain.proceed(newRequest)
                    }.build()
        }

        val awsConfig = AWSConfiguration(context)
            mAWSAppSyncClient = AWSAppSyncClient.builder()
                .context(context)
                .okHttpClient(client)
                .normalizedCache(mNormalizedCacheFactory)
                .resolver(cacheKeyResolver)
                .persistentMutationsCallback(object : PersistentMutationsCallback {
                    override fun onFailure(error: PersistentMutationsError?)
                    {
                        Log.v("dd","ff")
                    }
                    override fun onResponse(response: PersistentMutationsResponse?)
                    {
                        Log.v("dd","ff")
                    }
                })
                .awsConfiguration(awsConfig)
                .build()
        return mAWSAppSyncClient
    }       
}
```

}

// Mutation implementation

```
        val graphqlCallback = object : GraphQLCall.Callback<MessageActivityMutation.Data>() {
            override fun onResponse(response: Response<MessageActivityMutation.Data>) {
                if(response!=null){}                        
            }
            override fun onFailure(e: ApolloException) {
                e.printStackTrace()                   
            }
        }
        ClientFactory.getInstance(thiscontext!!,preferencesHelper!!.userAuthToken,"messageackmutation_db")
            ?.mutate(MessageActivityMutation.builder()
            .id(msg_id)
            .verb(Constants.MESSAGE_ACKNOWLEDGED)
            .actioned_at(timeStamp)
            .build())
            ?.enqueue(graphqlCallback)
```

LOGCAT DETAILS***

2019-10-25 17:57:35.180 5403-8062/com.envoyer.app D/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[23616]: Internet DISCONNECTED.
2019-10-25 17:57:35.196 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app I/timberLog: Info-->Plain or R&AK with attachments
2019-10-25 17:57:35.218 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:In Constructor
2019-10-25 17:57:35.218 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:Priming the pump - Fetching all the queued mutations from the persistent store
2019-10-25 17:57:35.218 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]: Fetching all mutation requests from persistent store
2019-10-25 17:57:35.220 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:Exiting the constructor. There are [0] mutations in the persistent queue
2019-10-25 17:57:35.225 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/AppSyncComplexObjectsInterceptor: Thread:[2]: Instantiating Complex Objects Interceptor
2019-10-25 17:57:35.235 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[2]: Processing mutation.
2019-10-25 17:57:35.235 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[2]: First, checking if it is a retry of mutation that encountered a conflict.
2019-10-25 17:57:35.235 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[2]:Nope, hasn't encountered  conflict
2019-10-25 17:57:35.237 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:  Added mutation[7ce851b7-fb8e-4ec2-ac49-4b603ca13acd] to inMemory Queue
2019-10-25 17:57:35.237 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/S3ObjectManagerImplementation: Thread:[2]: Looking at Key [id] of type [Integer]
2019-10-25 17:57:35.239 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/S3ObjectManagerImplementation: Thread:[2]: Looking at Key [verb] of type [String]
2019-10-25 17:57:35.242 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/S3ObjectManagerImplementation: Thread:[2]: Looking at Key [actioned_at] of type [String]
2019-10-25 17:57:35.247 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:addPersistentMutationObject: Adding mutation[7ce851b7-fb8e-4ec2-ac49-4b603ca13acd]: MessageActivityMutation 
    {"query":"mutation MessageActivity($id: Int, $verb: String, $actioned_at: String) {  MessageActivity(id: $id, verb: $verb, actioned_at: $actioned_at) {    __typename    status    data    message  }}","variables":{"id":1833,"verb":"message.seen","actioned_at":"2019-10-25 12:27:35"}}
2019-10-25 17:57:35.263 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]: Added mutation[7ce851b7-fb8e-4ec2-ac49-4b603ca13acd] to Persistent Queue. No S3 Objects found
2019-10-25 17:57:35.263 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]: Created both in-memory and persistent records. Now going to signal queue handler.
2019-10-25 17:57:35.263 5403-8068/com.envoyer.app V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[23622]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
2019-10-25 17:57:35.263 5403-8068/com.envoyer.app V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[23622]: Got message to process next mutation if one exists.
2019-10-25 17:57:35.264 5403-8068/com.envoyer.app V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[23622]: Internet wasn't available. Exiting
2019-10-25 17:57:35.281 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:In Constructor
2019-10-25 17:57:35.281 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:Priming the pump - Fetching all the queued mutations from the persistent store
2019-10-25 17:57:35.281 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]: Fetching all mutation requests from persistent store
2019-10-25 17:57:35.283 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:Exiting the constructor. There are [1] mutations in the persistent queue
2019-10-25 17:57:35.288 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/AppSyncComplexObjectsInterceptor: Thread:[2]: Instantiating Complex Objects Interceptor
2019-10-25 17:57:35.331 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:In Constructor
2019-10-25 17:57:35.331 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:Priming the pump - Fetching all the queued mutations from the persistent store
2019-10-25 17:57:35.331 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]: Fetching all mutation requests from persistent store
2019-10-25 17:57:35.333 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:Exiting the constructor. There are [1] mutations in the persistent queue
2019-10-25 17:57:35.337 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/AppSyncComplexObjectsInterceptor: Thread:[2]: Instantiating Complex Objects Interceptor
2019-10-25 17:57:35.357 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:In Constructor
2019-10-25 17:57:35.358 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:Priming the pump - Fetching all the queued mutations from the persistent store
2019-10-25 17:57:35.358 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]: Fetching all mutation requests from persistent store
2019-10-25 17:57:35.360 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:Exiting the constructor. There are [1] mutations in the persistent queue
2019-10-25 17:57:35.368 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/AppSyncComplexObjectsInterceptor: Thread:[2]: Instantiating Complex Objects Interceptor
2019-10-25 17:57:35.415 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:In Constructor
2019-10-25 17:57:35.415 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:Priming the pump - Fetching all the queued mutations from the persistent store
2019-10-25 17:57:35.415 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]: Fetching all mutation requests from persistent store
2019-10-25 17:57:35.417 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[2]:Exiting the constructor. There are [1] mutations in the persistent queue
2019-10-25 17:57:35.422 5403-5403/com.envoyer.app V/AppSyncComplexObjectsInterceptor: Thread:[2]: Instantiating Complex Objects Interceptor
2019-10-25 17:57:35.470 5403-8067/com.envoyer.app D/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[23621]: Internet DISCONNECTED.
2019-10-25 17:57:35.472 5403-8069/com.envoyer.app D/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[23623]: Internet DISCONNECTED.
2019-10-25 17:57:35.472 5403-8071/com.envoyer.app D/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[23625]: Internet DISCONNECTED.
2019-10-25 17:57:35.473 5403-8077/com.envoyer.app D/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[23628]: Internet DISCONNECTED.
2019-10-25 17:57:35.474 5403-8080/com.envoyer.app D/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[23630]: Internet DISCONNECTED.
2019-10-25 17:57:36.103 5403-8054/com.envoyer.app E/timberLog: onError-->An exception was thrown by the websocket
2019-10-25 17:57:37.759 5403-7658/com.envoyer.app V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[23596]: processing Mutations

******AFTER NETWORK ENABLED*******

<-- 200 https://4betrpovsffuhjxad5ouxlm6um.appsync-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/graphql (1824ms)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.140 5403-8282/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
2019-10-25 17:58:31.140 5403-8282/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: content-length: 100
2019-10-25 17:58:31.140 5403-8282/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: date: Fri, 25 Oct 2019 12:29:19 GMT
2019-10-25 17:58:31.140 5403-8282/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amzn-requestid: e351113d-b8b4-416c-855c-6c28c95f1a98
2019-10-25 17:58:31.140 5403-8282/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
2019-10-25 17:58:31.140 5403-8282/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: via: 1.1 bae54c9df29d44a26d5e0fd3d2c61c9c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.140 5403-8282/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amz-cf-pop: MAA50-C1
2019-10-25 17:58:31.141 5403-8282/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amz-cf-id: Pl8OYaRmtJxPinPXFbGwcnfgQxyGlWJo1LE0n9_oQprRKeULGsvkCw==
2019-10-25 17:58:31.141 5403-8282/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: {"data":{"MessageActivity":{"__typename":"Response","status":true,"data":"[]","message":"Success"}}}
2019-10-25 17:58:31.141 5403-8282/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (100-byte body)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.142 5403-8282/com.envoyer.app V/dd: ff
2019-10-25 17:58:31.142 5403-8282/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[23645]:Removing mutation [7ce851b7-fb8e-4ec2-ac49-4b603ca13acd] from persistent store
2019-10-25 17:58:31.209 5403-8054/com.envoyer.app I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
2019-10-25 17:58:31.271 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app I/RetryInterceptor: Returning network response: success
2019-10-25 17:58:31.271 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: <-- 200 https://4betrpovsffuhjxad5ouxlm6um.appsync-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/graphql (1900ms)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.271 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
2019-10-25 17:58:31.272 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: content-length: 100
2019-10-25 17:58:31.272 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: date: Fri, 25 Oct 2019 12:29:19 GMT
2019-10-25 17:58:31.272 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amzn-requestid: d0289bd6-3e31-49a6-815f-a708a1fa2233
2019-10-25 17:58:31.272 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
2019-10-25 17:58:31.272 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: via: 1.1 bae54c9df29d44a26d5e0fd3d2c61c9c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.272 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amz-cf-pop: MAA50-C1
2019-10-25 17:58:31.272 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amz-cf-id: 7wqu5JSmQJFT9layGkgpXB1WNpx5qD0-ohHF6TNHbU2l8gcBBUs0AQ==
2019-10-25 17:58:31.274 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: {"data":{"MessageActivity":{"__typename":"Response","status":true,"data":"[]","message":"Success"}}}
2019-10-25 17:58:31.274 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (100-byte body)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.276 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app V/dd: ff
2019-10-25 17:58:31.276 5403-8298/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[23648]:Removing mutation [7ce851b7-fb8e-4ec2-ac49-4b603ca13acd] from persistent store
2019-10-25 17:58:31.407 5403-8307/com.envoyer.app I/RetryInterceptor: Returning network response: success
2019-10-25 17:58:31.408 5403-8307/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: <-- 200 https://4betrpovsffuhjxad5ouxlm6um.appsync-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/graphql (2007ms)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.408 5403-8307/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
2019-10-25 17:58:31.408 5403-8307/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: content-length: 100
2019-10-25 17:58:31.408 5403-8307/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: date: Fri, 25 Oct 2019 12:29:19 GMT
2019-10-25 17:58:31.408 5403-8307/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amzn-requestid: 6a575625-f4fa-4209-ac5c-e47f88297910
2019-10-25 17:58:31.408 5403-8307/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
2019-10-25 17:58:31.409 5403-8307/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: via: 1.1 bae54c9df29d44a26d5e0fd3d2c61c9c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.409 5403-8307/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amz-cf-pop: MAA50-C1
2019-10-25 17:58:31.409 5403-8307/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amz-cf-id: 1RaLA8-nyDTGsreE4QmtMETeslLvw3PmnHHdMZqzTXsYSjg3Y3kVbQ==
2019-10-25 17:58:31.411 5403-8307/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: {"data":{"MessageActivity":{"__typename":"Response","status":true,"data":"[]","message":"Success"}}}
2019-10-25 17:58:31.411 5403-8307/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (100-byte body)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.469 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app I/RetryInterceptor: Returning network response: success
2019-10-25 17:58:31.469 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: <-- 200 https://4betrpovsffuhjxad5ouxlm6um.appsync-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/graphql (2152ms)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.469 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
2019-10-25 17:58:31.470 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: content-length: 100
2019-10-25 17:58:31.470 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: date: Fri, 25 Oct 2019 12:29:19 GMT
2019-10-25 17:58:31.470 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amzn-requestid: 509dfabd-008d-477b-8e0d-247c2db21ced
2019-10-25 17:58:31.470 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
2019-10-25 17:58:31.470 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: via: 1.1 bae54c9df29d44a26d5e0fd3d2c61c9c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.470 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amz-cf-pop: MAA50-C1
2019-10-25 17:58:31.470 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amz-cf-id: -rdF8loaCHAAmZN8-mRIp9EIYOPJ5ngimAwyisRkoLwXnU_VdrmNAw==
2019-10-25 17:58:31.471 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: {"data":{"MessageActivity":{"__typename":"Response","status":true,"data":"[]","message":"Success"}}}
2019-10-25 17:58:31.471 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (100-byte body)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.473 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app V/dd: ff
2019-10-25 17:58:31.473 5403-8281/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[23644]:Removing mutation [7ce851b7-fb8e-4ec2-ac49-4b603ca13acd] from persistent store
2019-10-25 17:58:31.508 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app I/RetryInterceptor: Returning network response: success
2019-10-25 17:58:31.509 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: <-- 200 https://4betrpovsffuhjxad5ouxlm6um.appsync-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/graphql (2182ms)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.509 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
2019-10-25 17:58:31.509 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: content-length: 100
2019-10-25 17:58:31.509 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: date: Fri, 25 Oct 2019 12:29:19 GMT
2019-10-25 17:58:31.509 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amzn-requestid: be28bb94-2788-449d-bc6f-af722e77e6d0
2019-10-25 17:58:31.509 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
2019-10-25 17:58:31.509 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: via: 1.1 bae54c9df29d44a26d5e0fd3d2c61c9c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.509 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amz-cf-pop: MAA50-C1
2019-10-25 17:58:31.509 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: x-amz-cf-id: edvrZI0GEB_1DDoikzUVcFjpwwyIGAXl9elEqbgk-_ShvoKsP86kuw==
2019-10-25 17:58:31.510 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: {"data":{"MessageActivity":{"__typename":"Response","status":true,"data":"[]","message":"Success"}}}
2019-10-25 17:58:31.511 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (100-byte body)
2019-10-25 17:58:31.512 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app V/dd: ff
2019-10-25 17:58:31.512 5403-8283/com.envoyer.app V/PersistentOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[23647]:Removing mutation [7ce851b7-fb8e-4ec2-ac49-4b603ca13acd] from persistent store
2019-10-25 17:58:31.685 5403-8282/com.envoyer.app V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[23645]: Setting mutationInProgress as false.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer but not really sure why this is happening. It's that besides overriding `onFailure` and `onSuccess` in your mutation you need to override another method i.e. `onStatusEvent` and clear the mutation queue. I believe that it's getting called twice or thrice sometimes once for scheduling and once for the network.

```
override fun onStatusEvent(event: GraphQLCall.StatusEvent) {
                    super.onStatusEvent(event)
                    awsAppSyncClient.clearMutationQueue()
                }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: **Tallal Tasawar**  Tried this but  the same issue still exists. Thanks!

Comment: Ideally, you should be handling this multiple on the backend by using an ID and the backend should check if the ID already exists it should not consider it as a new record.